# Show same values in same table cell

Tags: laravel, eloquent, bootstrap-4

I have table with columns headers like 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Now I need to show products with quantity 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 under each column, that is if there is a product with quantity 4, it will be shown under the column 4.

I have tried groupBy and foreach, but not getting expected result.

In my controller `$products = Product::all();`

In my view:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>

   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
   @for($i = 1; $i < 6; i++)
       @foreach($products as $product)
           @if($product->quantity == $i)
               <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
           @else
               <td>{{ "-" }}</td>
           @endif
       @endforeach
   @endfor
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$products = Product::get()->groupBy('quantity');
```

And then in your table:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>

   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
   @for($i = 1; $i <= 5; i++)
      @if(!empty($products[$i]))
         @foreach($products as $product)
             <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
         @endforeach  
      @else
         <td>-</td>
      @endif
   @endfor
   </tr>
</tbody>
```